# Difference between xsi:null and xsi:nil

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I've tried to put `XmlElementAttribue(IsNullable=true)`
On a property (property uses data member)

But, when I see the serialzed xml, I see `xsi:null=true`.

I want it to write `xsi:nil=true`

How can I do it?

Comment: This [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybce7f69(v=vs.85).aspx) should tell you everything you need

Comment: It doesn't help me, because there is no talking on xsi:null, I get xsi:null and I want to reach my code get an xsi:nil.

Another important thing, I'm trying to put xsi:nil on byte[] (byte array)

Comment: `xsi:nil` is part of [the XML schema spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_nil).  `xsi:null` isn't a thing.  If I serialize a null property with the attribute as you describe, I get `xsi:nil="true"`, so your issue isn't reproducible (see [this demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/A1v9yG)).

Comment: so why does the code serialize null property as xsi:null="true"

Comment: @SomeGuy it doesn't, I showed you it doesn't.  Can you give a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows it does?